# Why does the result of a mapping transducer include greater-than-2 arities?

Tags: clojure, arity, transducer

The question is in the title. Below I copy the transducer-part of the source of `map`:

```clj
([f]
  (fn [rf]
    (fn
      ([] (rf))
      ([result] (rf result))
      ([result input]
         (rf result (f input)))
      ([result input & inputs] ;why?
         (rf result (apply f input inputs))))))
```

Here is a link to [the source of `clojure.core`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj) which contains the definition of `map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` can work on multiple collections at once, calling the mapping function with an argument for each collection item:

```
(map + [1 2 3] [4 5 6])
=> (5 7 9)
```

The `+` function is invoked once for each pair of values in those collections e.g. `(+ 1 4)`, `(+ 2 5)`, `(+ 3 6)`. The non-transducer version looks like [this](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/0df3d8e2e27fb06fa53398754cac2be4878b12d1/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2772-L2778).

The `map` transducer works the same way:

```
(sequence (map +) [1 2 3] [4 5 6])
=> (5 7 9)
```

> [`map`] Returns a lazy sequence consisting of the result of applying f to
> the set of **first items of each coll**, followed by applying f to the
> set of **second items in each coll**, **until any one of the colls is
> exhausted**.  Any remaining items in other colls are ignored. Function
> f should accept number-of-colls arguments. Returns a transducer when
> no collection is provided.